# Hibernate java Mysql date are not sync

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date

I have a java code using Hibernate and Mysql.

I cant understand what happens to Dates between Mysql and Java? for example can any body explain why is the output of this code is `true`????

```
 Date d = something!
 Query q= HSF.get().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from BaseNotification where creationDate <= :maxd and creationDate >= :mind order by creationDate");
    q.setDate("maxd",new Date(d.getTime()+23*3600*1000+1155*1000));
    q.setDate("mind",new Date(d.getTime()+23*3600*1000+1154*1000+999));
    ((BaseNotification)q.list().get(0)).getCreationDate().equals(d); // why its true!!!!!!!
```

believe me I'm not kidding!!!! 
also if i get an object from hibernate with some date property and then want to get all objects with that date it doesn't even return the object itself!

my timezone is +3:30 is there any thing related to it?
but DB and Java code are in the same machine!.

Comment: what is something, and what date is being returned from the DB?

Comment: your comparing two dates using .equals() method. What is the result of "d" and getCreationDate()?

Comment: type of dates from Database is: java.sql.Timestamp